# MySQL - How to replace random 8 byte number to null

Tags: mysql, url, replace

I have following style url in the text body in mysql DB

- Type A: https://www.old_example1.com/12345678/myname
- Type B: https://www.old_example2.com/87654321/yourname

I would like to change the url to below format

- Type A: https://www.new_example1.com/myname
- Type B: http://www.new_example2.com/yourname

For the domain part, it is a simple replacement query, so no big deal. But the 8 byte random number part after the domain is kinda tricky.

I've tried to count text bytes and use substring, but the 'old_example1' and 'old_example2' part is not always consistent bytes. Sometimes it is 1~2 bytes longer or shorter. But the occurence of '/' is consistent, so I have tried to find a way to count '/' and replace numbers values btwn 3rd and 4th '/' to '' (empty value), but can't figure out how to apply such conditions.

Comment: That's not an 8-byte number, but an 8 digit number and you do not want to replace those by null as null concatenated by any other string will give you null. You want to replace those with empty string and prevent the duplication of `/`.

Comment: Use SUBSTRING_INDEX() function.

Comment: It's splitting hairs and not relevant to the question to call out the difference between 8 bytes and 8 digits in this case, because in ASCII, each character takes one byte.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Z7fV3ovQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

Here's a crude example:

```
SET @string = 'Some text https://www.old_example1.com/12345678/myname blah blah blah https://www.old_example2.com/87654321/yourname some more blah';

SELECT
    @string AS old_string,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        @string,
        'https:\/\/www\.old_example([1|2])\.com(\/[0-9]{8}\/)',
        'https://www.new_example$1.com/'
    ) AS new_string;
```

Outputs:

| old_string | new_string |
| --- | --- |
| Some text https://www.old_example1.com/12345678/myname blah blah blah https://www.old_example2.com/87654321/yourname some more blah | Some text https://www.new_example1.com/myname blah blah blah https://www.new_example2.com/yourname some more blah |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KvY_n6yX).

Comment: REGEXP looks more neat!

Comment: I eventually solved my puzzle with above wildcard type urls. It helped me to handle other similar cases more easily. Thx bunch!

Comment: The same request was for a single event, but there are similar cases across my server, so I had to manually apply modified ones. For now, it is finite number of responses to server issues, but later, if they come back to constantly like that, I have to add the line for instant transformation.

Answer (score 1):

As Shadow mentioned in the comments that's an 8 digit number, not 8-byte number.

If your string has always the following format , you could use substring_index function

> https://www.old_example1.com/12345678/myname
> https://www.old_example2.com/87654321/yourname

I am using `.com/` as a word to get the latest part of the string including the replaced one. I'm guessing `.com/` is repeated only once in your string, otherwise this answer will fail.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.com/',-1) AS extracted
FROM test;
```

Result

```
extracted
12345678/myname
87654321/yourname
```

Same thing as above to get the digits and to not include twice `/`

```
select concat('/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.com/',-1),'/',1)) as value_to_replace
FROM test;
```

Result

```
value_to_replace
/12345678
/87654321
```

Finally

```
select col,replace(col,concat('/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.com/',-1),'/',1)),'') as new_col
from test;
```

Result

```
col new_col
https://www.old_example1.com/12345678/myname    https://www.old_example1.com/myname
https://www.old_example2.com/87654321/yourname  https://www.old_example2.com/yourname
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/LVXhFYx2)

---

Comment: Thanks @Ergest Barsha (and Shadow) for pointing out the difference btwn byte and digits. I am sorry for the confusion. Indeed the substring index came acrossed my mind, but given the fact that the url is within the body of text post, I wasn't sure.  Working with concat, this looks like a solution for my problem. Thx bunch!